# mod_deflate is not working for php generated page

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.5, mod-deflate

`mod_deflate` not working for php generated page. I have **Apache v2.4.7** with **php v5.5.9** on **Ubuntu 14.04.5 (LTS)**. This module is working for static html pages and other files like CSS, js etc.

here is my php information http://www.hostnology.com/test.php

Comment: Note that [PHP 5.5 has been entirely unsupported for over a year](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) (it doesn't even receive security updates anymore). Furthermore, [PHP _5.5.9_ is an ancient version of the obsolete PHP 5.5 branch](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.9), nearly 3.5 years old. _**Please** upgrade to a supported version of PHP_. Upgrading your OS to a newer version of Ubuntu, like [16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/), is also a good idea and may help with the PHP upgrade.

Comment: @Chris it was working fine on my old server with Apache2.2 and php5.3

Comment: Sunny, I'm not trying to answer your question. I'm trying to give you some valuable advice: Don't just upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 (and especially not to version 5.5.9). PHP 5.5 is almost as bad as PHP 5.3 from a security perspective. _Please_ upgrade to at least version 5.6, which is the last version of PHP 5 that will be released and has therefore been given an extended security support period (until December 31, 2018).

Comment: your test.php sends `Content-Encoding: gzip`, so the page is gzipped. Note, the module do this due to a client's header `Accept-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: @Deadooshka I can't see **Content-Encoding: gzip** using command `curl -I  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://www.hostnology.com/test.php`

Comment: `-I` option means HEAD request method, so there is nothing to compress. Try `curl -i -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://www.hostnology.com/test.php` or even better `curl -i --compressed http://www.hostnology.com/test.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Only content is deflated, if you use HEAD http verb, there is no content, so no need to deflate it
- You can set (or there is) parameter in httpd that activate deflate on some mime type. (no need to deflate jpeg for instance)
- if content type is small (like <1k) there no point to deflate (size almost same)

Comment: you are right its working but not showing in curl. I can see it now with this command `curl -L -v -s -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -o /dev/null http://www.hostnology.com/test.php`